# Open a folder on a server directory from a link in Trello

Tags: trello

I want to be able to put a link in Trello that will help us to open directly a specific folder in Windows Explorer. Is that possible?

For example: if I type in `c:/` in Internet Explorer, it opens up C drive in Windows Explorer. What should I enter in Trello to open this way?

Comment: Can you clarify what this has to do with Trello?

Comment: At work, we use trello for management. But instead of putting some broken copy/paste link, I would actually be able to click on a link in a card of trello to go to a specific folder with the files we need. And this link will actually open windows explorer. Hope it helps...

Comment: This question has been reworded to fit the rules in the help center. Thank you to change the status of this question.

Answer (score 1):

- Internet Explorer supports this natively using the file://c:/ syntax.
- FireFox has a funky syntax and does not enable local file access by
  default
- Chrome does not support this

However, you can install browser extensions to both FireFox and Chrome to provide behavior consistent with Internet Explorer:

- [FireFox LocalLink](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/locallink/)
- [Chrome LocalLinks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida)

Comment: Thank you Jamie, unfortunately i have already tried this one. It will not open a 'windows explorer' window. Note that I want to open a specific folder from a web browser using the web app 'trello'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the notation `file:///C|/My%20Documents`. I haven't tested it in IE, but it sure works in Firefox.

Comment: Thank you for your time. The point is, trello is used with a web browser but we need to open the folder in a windows explorer window, not in the web browser. So, yes it open the folder, but still in a web browser interface. In the web browser windows (I use chrome) it will download the file instead of editing the source file. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also wish that this would work, but apparently Trello does not support this.  I am basing that on this help article from Trello - http://help.trello.com/article/1040-why-cant-i-open-file-links

In that article, they say that you cannot actually open a local file from Trello.  The best that you can do is open a file stored on a service like Google Drive, DropBox, Box, or OneDrive from Trello.  I suspect that the same is true for directories.

If storing the directory that you want to open on one of those services is acceptable, you might be able to take that approach.